# Accessing Elements of JS Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have created array in a object,

```
var obj_report_dailog = { array_report_dailog : [] }
```

Then push data to object,

```
obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog.push({from: fromDate})
obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog.push({to: toDate})
obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog.push({fabrika: fabrika})
```

Then,

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj_report_dialog);
```

How can I access to elements of that object?

```
console.log("işte bu: " + json);
```

output:

```
işte bu: {"array_report_dialog":[{"from":"2017-08-01"},{"to":"2017-09-21"},{"fabrika":["Balçova"]}]}
```

Comment: `json.array_report_dialog[0]`etc. just like a regular array.

Comment: Why are you doing `JSON.stringify`, when you want to access json/object?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: Not "json/object", just object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't want to `JSON.stringify` unless you're sending the resulting **string** somewhere that will parse it. Remember, JSON is a **textual** notation for data exchange; `JSON.stringify` gives you a string to send to some receiver. When you have the JSON string, you **don't** access the properties of the objects in it.

   If you're *receiving* that JSON string, you'd parse it via `JSON.parse` and then access the properties on the result.
2. Leaving aside the JSON thing, you probably don't want to add data the way you're adding it. You're adding three separate objects as three entries in the array, each with one property. You probably want to push **one** object with all three properties:

   ```
   obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog.push({
       from: fromDate,
       to: toDate,
       fabrika: fabrika
   });
   ```

   Then you'd access them as `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[0].from`, `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[0].to`, and `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[0].fabrika`. Or more likely, you'd have a loop like this:

   ```
   obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog.forEach(function(entry) {
       // Use entry.from, entry.to, and entry.fabrika here
   });
   ```

   (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for more options for looping through arrays.)

   **But**, if you really want to push them as separate objects, you'd access them as `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[0].from`, `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[1].to`, and `obj_report_dialog.array_report_dialog[2].fabrika` (note the indexes going up).

Answer (score 1):

If you `stringify` a `json`, it's gonna create a string representation of your object.

To access data in a string like that we usually use `JSON.parse` that create an json object from a string. Which is the `obj_report_dailog` you had at start.

Answer (score 0):

You can make object from json by using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse(json).array_report_dialog
```